# How to generate a reset password token

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to generate a reset password token but I get undefined method signed_id. This is what i have tried.

in the password_mailer.rb

```
def reset
  params[:user]

  mail to: params[:user].email
end
```

password_resets_controller.rb

```
 def create
    @user = User.find_by(email: params[:email])

    if @user.present?
     PasswordMailer.with(user: @user).reset.deliver_now
    end
    redirect_to root_path, notice: "We have sent a link to reset your password"
  end
```

and in the console

```
user = User.last
user.signed_id
```

i get the error in the console saying undefined method signed_id. I don't understand why because the signed_id comes from Active Record. Anyone to explain to me?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you use Ruby on Rails older than 6.1, because `signed_id` can be called on active records only in 6.1 and newer.

For Rails < 6.1 I would use:

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_secure_token :password_reset_token
end

# Generating a token:

def generate_token(user)
  user = User.last
  user.regenerate_password_reset_token

  # add next line if you want it to be expirable
  user.password_reset_token_created_at = Time.zone.now

  user.save!
end

# Finding by token:
def find_by_token(token)
  User.find_by(password_reset_token: token)
end

# Finding by token if it is expirable
def find_by_token(token)
  User.where(
    "password_reset_token = ? AND password_reset_token_created_at >= ?",
    token,
    15.minutes.ago # expiration time
  ).first
end
```

Also you should add `password_reset_token` column to `users` table in migration:

```rb
def change
  add_column :users, :password_reset_token, :string
  
  # add next line if you want it to be expirable
  add_column :users, :password_reset_token_created_at, :datetime
end
```

Comment: yes please. i use 6.0.3. So in this case how do i go about it?

Comment: @codetalkertive, just updated the answer.